# Saving pop-up configurations in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, popup

I would like to re-use a pop-up that has been previously configured in ArcGIS Pro.

Is there a way to do this?

I use ArcGIS Pro 3.2

Comment: If you configure your pop-up with arcade expression you could copy the code. But I don't think there is something like copy pop-up like copy symbology from antother layer or you use arcpy.

Comment: Try sharing your layer to a layer file (lyrx). This will save the symbology and I believe the pop-up configuration. But you would only be able to import it to another layer as long as the layer you are importing into is the same geometry type.

Comment: Similar to @Hornbydd's previous comment, you could copy/paste the layer as a new (duplicate) layer, then go into the new layer's properties and change the layer source.  But again, this would only work if the new layer source (feature class) had the same geometry type as the old one.